# Difference between power amplifier and voltage amplifier!

Tags: power-electronics

What are the major difference between power amplifier and voltage amplifier?

Comment: Do you know the difference between voltage and power?

Comment: What makes you think there are such things as strictly voltage amplifiers and power amplifiers?  It seems you don't really know what amplifiers are in general, else you wouldn't be asking this rather meaningless question.

Comment: this sounds like a school question .... why are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

A voltage amplifier takes a small voltage signal, say in the millivolt range, and outputs a similar signal that is scaled by some multiple (the gain) of the original signal. This gain can be > 1, = 1 (buffer), or < 1.

A power amplifier, in the context of practical electronics, uses a small incoming signal (typically voltage or current) to control a large amount of power (volts x amps). "Large" is relative to the input signal; the power amplification stage of a guitar amp might only handle a few watts, while a generator voltage regulator's power stage might handle hundreds or thousands of watts.

Designers don't conceptually consider a power amplifier as a device that uses a small power input to control a large power output. As stated above, you'd input a voltage or current.